# Are there any C++ graphic libraries for mobile?

Tags: c++, mobile

I’m currently attempting to design a Pong clone as a way of testing my coding abilities. However, being on mobile, I can’t use a keyboard as an input to move the paddle, so I must use buttons, or some other method that involves the touch screen.

After doing some research, it seems most people just use a graphic library like SFML to handle things like buttons or sliders. Unfortunetaly, all of the graphic library that I have found aren’t compatible with mobile, and so I’m not sure where to go from here.

Basically, I’m looking for a graphic library that’ll work on mobile.
If it helps, I’m on an iPhone 7 running iOS 13.6, and I’m using repl.it to write in C++.

P.S.
Of course, if there is another way to use the touchscreen as an input that doesn’t involve graphic libraries, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Sorry, recommendations of software libraries, tools, and other products is off-topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: almost ten years ago there already were solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375383 So, yeah, there definitely are options

Comment: There's also https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Mobile/index.html

Comment: See SFML & libGDX libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL2 has pretty nice support for mobile stuff, including iOS. There's a nice explanation/intro [here](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/52_hello_mobile/index2.php)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work quite well. (Also, sorry for off-topic question :/)